# Does Visual Studio 2019 have a form designer for c++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Before deciding to download Visual Studio 2019, I just wanted to know whether a visual form designer is available that generates c++ code.

If not, does anyone know of an easy to use development environment that does?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it can no longer be activated.  No other IDE has a C++/CLI designer, resorting to VS2010 is best.

Comment: Thanks!  Would you know where might I find such old software?  And does it run on Windows 10?

Comment: Found it at archive.org.  https://archive.org/download/vs-2010-express-1/VS2010Express1.iso

Comment: According to your description, whether you want to create C++ Windows Forms application in Visual Studio? If so I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a9529502-6304-4aa6-90ee-0757ab258d87/create-c-windows-forms-application-in-visual-studio-2017?forum=winforms

And maybe you want to use MFC?

Comment: @HansPassant: Looks like Qt still does - it's pretty much their historical core business.